# Реализовать поиск по вхождению с начала строки node.js (postgres)

Tags: node.js, postgresql

подскажите пожалуйста, не могу реализовать поиск по вхождению с начала строки. В базе таблица words, колонка с данными search-word. Реализован метод получения списка. Добавить поиск, фильтрацию не удается. Скорее всего ошибка в написании функции или SQL запроса.

router.js

```
router.get('/list', listController.searchList)
```

controller.js

```
async searchList(req, res) {
try{
  const searchList = await listService.searchList()

  return res.json(searchList)

}catch{
  console.log(err)
}
}
```

service.js

```
 async searchList() {
const q = req.query.q;

const findWord = await db.query('SELECT * FROM words WHERE "search-word" LIKE $1', [q + '%'])
console.log(findWord)

return findWord; 
}
```

запрос в POSTMAN
http://localhost:3000/api/list?q=аспирин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `const searchList = await listService.searchList()` при вызове searchList вы ничего не передаёте, почему?

Comment: Даже если передавать параметр, не фильтрует. Если я правильно понял.

`const q = req.params.q`

`const searchList = await listService.searchList(q)`

Comment: попробуй написать просто `db.query(\`SELECT * FROM words WHERE "search-word" ILIKE '%аспирин%'\`)` - работает?

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, проблема была в SQL запросе некорректном и не передал параметр в функцию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел проблему. Некорректный SQL запрос + необходимо было передавать параметр в функцию.
service.js

```
async searchList(tag) {

    const findWord = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM words WHERE "search-word" ILIKE $1`, [tag + '%']);

    return words; 

  }
```

controller.js

```
async searchList(req, res) {
    try{
      const tag = req.query.q
      const searchList = await listService.searchList(tag)

      return res.json(searchList)

    }catch{
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```